# Bash Scripting Output

Tags: bash, dns, ip, dig

So my bash scripting is not the best, but the following script takes IP addresses from a text file and feeds the output to a shell and shows only the dns host names that resolve.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
dig @1.2.3.4 -x  "$line" +short
done
```

and the output would look like:

```
one.foo.local
two.foo.local
three.foo.local
```

How can I also print the ip address for the address that resolve to a dns name on the same line so it would appear like:

```
one.foo.local 2.3.4.5
two.foo.local 6.7.8.9
three.foo.local 7.5.3.1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
nme=$(dig @1.2.3.4 -x  "$line" +short)
if [ "$(echo "$nme"|wc -c)" -gt 1 ]
   then
    echo "$nme $line"
fi 
done<input_file
```

Comment: That prints out all of the ip addresses. I only wish to print the address that are resolved to a name.  One stop closer.  Thanks.

Comment: @SilverSurfer can you clarify what do you mean by "only wish to print the address that are resolved to a name". Please provide in question a example

Comment: @roaima, i get the point, let me edit the code :)

Comment: Exactly Romeo.  unresolved not on the list

Comment: @SilverSurfer, check the edited answer

Comment: @Romeo Ninov, Nope.  Still showing unresolved ip addresses in ouput.

Comment: @SilverSurfer, now should work

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much.  what does the -gt do?

Comment: `-gt` (great than) is arithmetic compare of two numbers (number of characters in resolved name) and 1 )